# Prevent CKEditor from removing escaped html

Tags: escaping, ckeditor

It's kinda hard to explain, but, basically, I have a website about coding, and I have some HTML code samples in the articles. The < and > characters in the code are, off course, escaped, but when i try to edit the article (I load it from database and populate the CKEditor's < textarea > with it), the ckeditor replaces my code with a bunch of &nbsp;s... Also, I don't want to disable the escaping completely...

Answer (score 1):

When you output code to `<textarea>` you must encode it because browser will decode entities when reading its value. In PHP for example you can do this:

```
<textarea ...>
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars( $content ); ?>
</textarea>
```

See for example http://ckeditor.com/comment/131972#comment-131972 for more details.